# How to force SSH to fail instead of password input session when the key pair is not valid?

Tags: ssh, automation, certificate

When I connect to remote machine using SSH, it asks me to input password if the key pair is invalid.

```
ssh -i keyfile root@server.com
root@server.com's password:
```

How can I force SSH to fail instead of asking when the key pair file is invalid? This is for bash script automation.

Comment: I believe this is something that should be configured on the server's side.

Comment: SSH doesn't normally use "certificates". Please replace the confusing word unless you really use X.509 certificate for SSH authentication.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I fixed it. Is it fine now? Or please suggest me proper wording.

Answer (score 0):

Disable standard input with `ssh -n`